# Http failure response for put method in angular 2 with asp.net webapi

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am facing "Http failure response" for put method, when i try to update my userdetails on userdetails page of my angular 2 application.
Can any one provide me idea to fix the following error.

Error:-
Message: "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost/TestWebAPI/api/UserDetails: 405 Method Not Allowed"

userdetails.component.ts

```ts
onUpdateUserClick(index)
{   
    this.objuserservice.UpdateUser(this.UpdateUser).subscribe
    (
        (response) => {
            this.UpdateUser = response;
            this.userslist[this.updateIndex].email = this.UpdateUser.email;
            this.userslist[this.updateIndex].personname = this.UpdateUser.personname;
            this.userslist[this.updateIndex].mobile = this.UpdateUser.mobile;
            this.userslist[this.updateIndex].dateofbirth = this.UpdateUser.dateofbirth;
            this.userslist[this.updateIndex].monthofbirth = this.UpdateUser.monthofbirth;this.userslist[this.updateIndex].yearofbirth=this.UpdateUser.yearofbirth;
            this.userslist[this.updateIndex].gender = this.UpdateUser.gender;
            this.userslist[this.updateIndex].country = this.UpdateUser.country;
        },
        (error)=>{ 
        });  
}
```

users.service.ts

```ts
UpdateUser(userobj:User):Observable<User>
{
    return this.http.put<User>(`/TestWebAPI/api/UserDetails`,userobj,responseType:"json"});              
}
```

Here is my asp.netwebapi(TestWebAPI) project code,

```cs
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]user objuser)
{
    dbentity.Entry(objuser).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    dbentity.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a problem that you are not passing that `id`? You could try to modify your method to be just `public void Put([FromBody]user objuser)` and put a breakpoint in the method just for testing, to see if that request would be correctly handled.

Comment: On second thought, if you have the default routes in Web API, maybe you should pass that `id` in the URL, from Angular, like `this.http.put<User>("/TestWebAPI/api/UserDetails/" + userObj.Id, userobj, responseType:"json"});`.

Comment: Thanks Dan , it works

Comment: @rajula - Great, I've made an answer out of that comment, so it would be more visible, you can accept it if you want.

Comment: yes, i accept it with happiness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the default routes in Web API, you should pass that `id` in the URL from Angular, like:

```ts
UpdateUser(userobj:User):Observable<User>
{  
    this.http.put<User>("/TestWebAPI/api/UserDetails/" + userObj.Id, userobj,
        responseType:"json"});
}
```